# Haskell(GHC) specialization tour & efficient TypeFamilies

Tags: performance, haskell, ghc, type-families

Haskell is all about abstraction. But abstraction costs us extra CPU cycles and extra memory usage due to common representation of all abstract (polymorphic) data - pointer on heap. There are some ways to make abstract code play better with high performance demands. As far as I understand, one way it is done is specialization - basically extra code generation(manual or by compiler), correct ?

Let's assume that all code below is **Strict**(which helps compiler perform more optimizations ?)

If we have a function `sum`:

```
sum :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a
```

We can generate specialized version of it using `specialize` pragma:

```
{-#SPECIALIZE sum :: Float -> Float -> Float#-}
```

Now if haskell compiler can determine at compile time that we call `sum` on two `Float`s, it is going to use specialized version of it. No heap allocations, right ?

Functions - done. Same pragma can be applied to class instances. Logic does not change here, does it ?

But what about data types ?
I suspect that `TypeFamilies` are in charge here ?

Let's try to specialize dependent length-indexed list.

```
--UVec for unboxed vector
class UVec a where
   data Vec (n :: Nat) a :: *

instance UVec Float where
   data Vec n Float where
     VNilFloat :: Vec 0 Float
     VConsFloat :: {-#UNPACK#-}Float ->
                   Vec n Float -> 
                   Vec (N :+ 1) Float
```

But `Vec` has a problem. We can't pattern match on its constructors as
each instance of `UVec` does not have to provide `Vec` with identical constructors. This forces us to implement each function on `Vec` for each instance of `Vec` (as lack of pattern matching implies that it can't be polymorphic on `Vec`). What is the best practice in such case ?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, we can't pattern match on `UVec a` without knowing what `a` is.
One option is to use another typeclass that extends your vector class with a custom function.

```
class UVec a => UVecSum a where
   sum :: UVec a -> a

instance UVecSum Float where
   sum = ... -- use pattern match here
```

If, later on, we use `sum v` where `v :: UVec Float`, the `Float`-specific code we defined in the instance will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, but perhaps it might help.

> As far as I understand, one way it is done is specialization - basically extra code generation(manual or by compiler), correct ?

Yes, this is similar to code instantiation in C++ templates.

> Now if haskell compiler can determine at compile time that we call sum on two Floats, it is going to use specialized version of it. No heap allocations, right ?

Yes the compiler calls the specialised version whenever possible. Not sure what you mean regarding the heap allocations.

Regarding the dependently types vectors: usually (I know this from Idris) the length of the vector is eliminated by the compiler when possible. It is intended for stronger type checking. At runtime the length information is useless and can be dropped.

Comment: About runtime length info : haskell does not have full dependent types. Haskell has distinction between runtime values and types. So the length of the Vec is guaranteed to be erased (as the length is a type (or kind) not runtime value but haskell does not allow types to be preserved at runtime) .